# How to get the key and value pair from a list of dictionary in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to the Python dev. below is my test code:

```
my_dict = [{'IS_DUMMY': False, 'FACT_CURRENCY': '$', 'RETAILER_NAME': 'kohls', 'RETAILER_KEY': 5, 'ACTIVE': 'Y'},{'IS_DUMMY': False, 'FACT_CURRENCY': '$', 'RETAILER_NAME': 'target', 'RETAILER_KEY': 100, 'ACTIVE': 'Y'}]

column_list = [{'SOURCE_COLUMN':'FACT_CURRENCY', 'TARGET_COLUMN':'CURRENCY'},{'SOURCE_COLUMN':'RETAILER_NAME', 'TARGET_COLUMN':'RETAILER'},
{'SOURCE_COLUMN':'RETAILER_KEY', 'TARGET_COLUMN':'KEY'},{'SOURCE_COLUMN':'ACTIVE', 'TARGET_COLUMN':'ACTIVE'}]
```

Here is my question: 
1. I need to find if the value of SOURCE_COLUMN from column_list is available in my_dict or not.(I am able to find that)
2. I need to create a list of dict which contain only the matching value from column_list in the my_dict. so my new list of dict will look like below:

```
my_new_dict = [{'FACT_CURRENCY': '$', 'RETAILER_NAME': 'kohls', 'RETAILER_KEY': 5, 'ACTIVE': 'Y'},{'FACT_CURRENCY': '$', 'RETAILER_NAME': 'target', 'RETAILER_KEY': 100, 'ACTIVE': 'Y'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your questions more readable you should put code on extra lines and indent them by 4 spaces, like this:

```
# your data:
my_dicts = [{'IS_DUMMY': False, 'FACT_CURRENCY': '$', 'RETAILER_NAME': 'kohls', 'RETAILER_KEY': 5, 'ACTIVE': 'Y'},{'IS_DUMMY': False, 'FACT_CURRENCY': '$', 'RETAILER_NAME': 'target', 'RETAILER_KEY': 100, 'ACTIVE': 'Y'}]
column_list = [{'SOURCE_COLUMN':'FACT_CURRENCY', 'TARGET_COLUMN':'CURRENCY'},{'SOURCE_COLUMN':'RETAILER_NAME', 'TARGET_COLUMN':'RETAILER'}, {'SOURCE_COLUMN':'RETAILER_KEY', 'TARGET_COLUMN':'KEY'},{'SOURCE_COLUMN':'ACTIVE', 'TARGET_COLUMN':'ACTIVE'}]

# seems like we only need the SOURCE_COLUMN entries from the column_list
source_cols = [col['SOURCE_COLUMN'] for col in column_list]

# iterate over my_dicts and create a new dictionary for each my_dict using
new_dicts = []
for my_dict in my_dicts:
    new_dicts.append({col:my_dict[col] for col in source_cols if col in my_dict})
```

Also see [PEP 274 -- Dict Comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of making `new_dicts` would be via a list comprehension:

```
new_dicts = [{col:my_dict[col] for col in source_cols if col in my_dict} for my_dict in my_dicts]
```

if you like Shubit's answer, consider upvoting it too :)

Comment: new_dicts.append({col['SOURCE_COLUMN']:my_dict[col['TARGET_COLuUMN'] for col in column_list if col['TARGET_COLUMN'] in my_dict})

Comment: @k-menyah You can use list comprehension, but for readability I would prefer not to, even so I love this compact syntax :)

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way i can update the source column with the target column from the column_list in the new dict? @Shubit